# WeightedData - error: is not a valid weight specification

Tags: functions, function-construction, warning-messages

I am importing a .dat file that contains two columns of data and performing various statistical analyses on the data. Column 1 is the dataset and column 2 is the uncertainties (sigma) in the values of column 1. I can not get `WeightedData` to work properly. The weight (`w`) is set to `1/sigma^2` and I keep getting the error that this is not a valid weight specification. How do I resolve this error?

```
$Path = Append[$Path, "c:"]
grades = OpenRead["grades.dat"]
data = ReadList[grades, {Number, Number}]
Close[grades]
Mean[data[[All, 1]]] // N
StandardDeviation[data[[All, 1]]] // N
w = (1/({data[[All, 2]]}^2)) // N
data2 = {data[[All, 1]]}
\[ScriptCapitalA] = WeightedData[data2, w]
```

> ```
> InputStream["grades.dat", 3]
>
> {{42, 47}, {40, 9.2}, {4, 9.5}, {36, 83.6}, {45, 9.5}, {35, 8.9}, {78,
>    53}, {1000, 9.5}, {423, 7.8}, {85, 9.3}, {934, 959}, {84, 
>   9.2}, {59, 7.8}, {33, 7.7}, {62, 7.9}, {53, 77}, {33, 9.2}, {81, 
>   9}, {65, 8.1}, {33, 8.6}, {69, 8.5}, {69, 42.7}, {53, 7.7}, {55, 
>   7.5}, {33, 8.4}, {82, 9}, {81, 9}, {76, 8.9}, {2076, 9.3}, {83, 
>   9.3}, {74, 8.9}, {86, 8.9}, {78, 9.2}, {43, 7.7}, {66, 8.3}, {60, 
>   7.8}, {68, 8.3}, {92, 10}, {1365, 9.5}, {86, 67}, {88, 6.8}, {43, 
>   45.3}, {78, 54.6}, {77, 42.4}, {67, 54}, {45, 34}, {33, 56}, {102, 
>   722}, {56, 54}, {55, 54}}
>
> grades.dat
>
> 171.28
>
> 376.54
>
> {{0.000452694, 0.0118147, 0.0110803, 0.000143083, 0.0110803, 
>   0.0126247, 0.000355999, 0.0110803, 0.0164366, 0.011562, 
>   1.08733*10^-6, 0.0118147, 0.0164366, 0.0168663, 0.0160231, 
>   0.000168663, 0.0118147, 0.0123457, 0.0152416, 0.0135208, 0.0138408, 
>   0.000548459, 0.0168663, 0.0177778, 0.0141723, 0.0123457, 0.0123457, 
>   0.0126247, 0.011562, 0.011562, 0.0126247, 0.0126247, 0.0118147, 
>   0.0168663, 0.0145159, 0.0164366, 0.0145159, 0.01, 0.0110803, 
>   0.000222767, 0.0216263, 0.000487308, 0.00033544, 0.000556248, 
>   0.000342936, 0.000865052, 0.000318878, 1.91834*10^-6, 0.000342936, 
>   0.000342936}}
>
> {{42, 40, 4, 36, 45, 35, 78, 1000, 423, 85, 934, 84, 59, 33, 62, 53, 
>   33, 81, 65, 33, 69, 69, 53, 55, 33, 82, 81, 76, 2076, 83, 74, 86, 
>   78, 43, 66, 60, 68, 92, 1365, 86, 88, 43, 78, 77, 67, 45, 33, 102, 
>   56, 55}}
> ```
>
> WeightedData: The argument 
>   {{0.000452694, 0.0118147, 0.0110803, 0.000143083, 0.0110803, 0.0126247, 0.000355999, 0.0110803, 0.0164366, 0.011562, <<30>>, 0.0216263, 0.000487308, 0.00033544, 0.000556248, 0.000342936, 0.000865052, 0.000318878, 1.91834*10^-6, 0.000342936, 0.000342936}} is not a valid weight specification.
>
> ```
> WeightedData[{{42, 40, 4, 36, 45, 35, 78, 1000, 423, 85, 934, 84, 59, 
>    33, 62, 53, 33, 81, 65, 33, 69, 69, 53, 55, 33, 82, 81, 76, 2076, 
>    83, 74, 86, 78, 43, 66, 60, 68, 92, 1365, 86, 88, 43, 78, 77, 67, 
>    45, 33, 102, 56, 55}}, {{0.000452694, 0.0118147, 0.0110803, 
>    0.000143083, 0.0110803, 0.0126247, 0.000355999, 0.0110803, 
>    0.0164366, 0.011562, 1.08733*10^-6, 0.0118147, 0.0164366, 
>    0.0168663, 0.0160231, 0.000168663, 0.0118147, 0.0123457, 0.0152416,
>     0.0135208, 0.0138408, 0.000548459, 0.0168663, 0.0177778, 
>    0.0141723, 0.0123457, 0.0123457, 0.0126247, 0.011562, 0.011562, 
>    0.0126247, 0.0126247, 0.0118147, 0.0168663, 0.0145159, 0.0164366, 
>    0.0145159, 0.01, 0.0110803, 0.000222767, 0.0216263, 0.000487308, 
>    0.00033544, 0.000556248, 0.000342936, 0.000865052, 0.000318878, 
>    1.91834*10^-6, 0.000342936, 0.000342936}}]
> ```

Comment: the way the last code segment is presented (the `WeightedData` part) seems to have an extra set of curly braces around both the data and weights; if you remove these extra braces, `WeightedData` executes normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra braces in your expressions for `data1` and `w`. The following revision of your code works.

```
data = {{42, 47}, {40, 9.2}, {4, 9.5}};
data2 = data[[All, 1]] // N;
w = 1/(data[[All, 2]]^2) // N;
WeightedData[data2, w]
```

[image: result]

#### Update

Some advice. Your code can be made simpler and will run faster if you avoid evaluating forms like `data[[All, 1]]` multiple times. Instead, write code like this:

```
data = {{42, 47}, {40, 9.2}, {4, 9.5}, {36, 83.6}, {45, 9.5}, {35, 8.9}};
{data1, data2} = Transpose[data // N];
Mean[data1]
```

> `33.6667`

```
StandardDeviation[data1]
```

> `15.0022`

```
w = 1/(data2^2);
\[ScriptCapitalA] = WeightedData[data1, w]
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you m_goldberg.  That fixed my error.

Comment: @Amy. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.

Comment: Absolutely. Thx again!  I’m just learning Mathmatica and am grateful for the assistance